# MatchIt in R - how to link/know which rows were matched to original dataset

Tags: r

I've ran the `MatchIt` package successfully using the nearest method, and got a new dataset with only matched rows.

I need to find which rows in the original dataset were matched, so that I can further describe the matched population (based on variables that aren't included in the propensity score matching). But, the matched output data only shows the variables that the regression was performed on.

reprex:

```
original_data <- data.frame(c(row_ID = 1232451, 4938593, 2948201, 3349281, 3958593, 3948202, 2938402, 1192932), wealth = c(low, med, high, med, high, med, low, med), income = c(50000,1000000,150000, 52000, 29000, 29330, 20000, 10292), marriage_status = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), death = c(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1))


ps <- glm(death ~ wealth + income, family = binomial(), data = original)

ps_df <- data.frame(pr_score = predict(ps, type = "response"),
                    readmit = ps$model$death)



ps_match <- matchit(death ~ wealth + income, method = "nearest", data = original_data)


ps_data <- match.data(ps_match)
View(ps_data)
```

How do I link the row ID in the new dataset ps_data so I know which rows were included from the original dataset?

Comment: would anyone be able to help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not runnable, so this is not a reprex. That said, `match.data()` uses the original dataset that was supplied to `matchit()`, so it automatically includes all the variables, whether they were used for matching or not. You can also set `drop.unmatched = FALSE` to make sure the original dataset and the matched dataset have the same number of rows (and unmatched units will receive a weight of 1 and a subclass of `NA`).

If for some reason your variable of interest is in a totally different dataset, you can subset that dataset using the row names of the matched dataset, e.g., using `merge()` with `by = 0` (which matches on row names).